# Select one row only from HSQLDB with Oracle dialect

Tags: sql, hsqldb

As the title suggests I need to select one row (no matter what is) from my query. `ROWNUM` doesn't work in HSQLDB as there is `ROWNUM()` function. What's more, setting ORA dialect both in connection url settings and in `schema-hsqldb.sql` doesn't work (it should but it doesn't, I don't know why). Query is fully working in Oracle.

Any suggestions? Thank you very much for any!

Comment: What happens when you run your query with rownum()? E.g. `select * from my_table where rownum() = 1`

Comment: @kfinity thanks for willingness to help! it gives me `SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about three days of searching, crying and thinking of committing suicide I've found that in my case (I have fairly complex SQL)  Hibernate prefixes `ROWNUM` with `THIS_` thinking it is a column. I've added the following custom dialect resolver and now it works:

```
public class RownumStandardDialectResolver extends StandardDialectResolver {

    @Override
    public Dialect resolveDialect(DialectResolutionInfo info) {
        Dialect dialect = super.resolveDialect(info);
        dialect.getKeywords().add("rownum");

        return dialect;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

An error occurs if you use `ROWNUM()`, instead of simple `ROWNUM`, without parentheses. Not sure how it is managed in HSQLDB.

Since you are using 12c, you could use `FETCH..FIRST..ONLY` in place of `ROWNUM`.

```
select * from employees  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

In lower versions, you could use `row_number()`, provided you have at least one `UNIQUE KEY` (not necessarily a declared constraint, but a set of columns to identify unique rows) on the table.

```
select b.<columns>  FROM
(
  select t.*, row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY <unique_key_column_s) rn  from yourtable  t
) b WHERE  b.rn = 1;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! it's great to see a person trying to help me with this:) however, the problem with `ROWNUM` occurs in tests, not in application running. `FETCH..FIRST..ONLY` doesn't work too: `HsqlException: unexpected token: SELECT`. and I don't have a unique column other than id:c